# Android: Periodic Drops In TCP Connection

Tags: java, android, performance, tcp

I have an Android app which connects to a camera over WiFi through TCP; app continuously receives data from Camera and display it as a video.

My problem is app periodically drops transfer rate to 0 (approximately every 10 ms) and after that it immediately come back to its previous value. Below you can see a screenshot of network activity through Profiler.

[image: Periodic Drop]

I find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995105/why-is-android-dropping-tcp-packets-occurs-in-droid-5-x-not-in-4-x) which was left unanswered some time ago.

I also set `WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF` & `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` but didn't fix the issue.

Any idea/suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see no periodic drop. I see a sawtooth. There is not a single period where the transfer rate is constant when i have to believe that picture.

Comment: @blackapps Okay, is there a way to keep the amount of data transferred somewhat stable at a given moment - like instead of sending 4mbs and then 0 and then 4 again, send something like 1-2 mb always?